# using Kotlin with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I'm new to `Kotlin` and `Gradle`, and tried to follow [these](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies) steps, so I got the following 2 files:

after running `gradle init` I changed the `build.gradle` to be:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "hello.main"

// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

`Hello.kt`:

```
package hello   

fun main(args: Array<String>) {   
   println("Hello World!")        
}
```

Then I run the `gradle build` and got the `build\classes\main\hello\HelloKt.class`

my question is: Why the file generated is `.class` not `.jar` and how to get the `.jar` file and how to run it, I tried running the generated file using `kotlin -classpath HelloKt.class main` but got an error `error: could not find or load main class hello.main`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @hotkey answer, it helped me going the correct way.

First of all there is a mistake in the main class declaration, as it should follow the new methodology, that is in the below format:

```
mainClassName = '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
```

namespace = package name

arctifact = file name

so, considering the names given in the example above where filename is: `Hello.kt`, and the namespace is `hello`, then:

```
mainClassName = `[hello].[Hello]Kt`
```

using the previous method, that contains:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.HelloKt'
```

the generated .jar file is not including the kotlin runtime, so the only way to execute it, is by:

```
d:/App/build/libs/kotlin -cp App.jar hello.HelloKt
```

but in order to generate a self contained `jar` that can be self-executed, and contains the `kotlin runtime` then the `build.gradle` should be written as:

```
// set up the kotlin-gradle plugin
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// apply the kotlin-gradle plugin
apply plugin: "kotlin"


// add kotlin-stdlib dependencies.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        //Define mainClassName as: '[your_namespace].[your_arctifact]Kt'
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'hello.HelloKt'
    }

    // NEW LINE HERE !!!
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}
```

followed by `gradle build`, the `[your_working_folder].jar` file will be generated at the `build/libs` folder, assuming the working folder name is app, then file app.jar will be generated.

To run this file, one of the following 2 commands can be used:

```
D:\App\build\libs\java -jar App.jar
```

OR

```
D:\App\build\libs\kotlin App.jar hello.HelloKt
```

Answer (score 2):

The classes are the direct output of the Kotlin compiler, and they should be packaged into a JAR by Gradle afterwards. To build a JAR, you can run the `jar` task, just as you would in a Java project:

```
gradle jar
```

<sup>This task is usually run during `gradle build` as well, due to the task dependencies.</sup>

This will pack the Kotlin classes into a JAR archive (together with other JVM classes, if you have a multi-language project), normally located at `build/libs/yourProjectName.jar`.

As to running the JAR, see this Q&A for a detailed explanation: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733566/how-to-run-kotlin-class-from-the-command-line)

Comment: I've no JAVA experience, I run `gradle jar` but I found this file only `build/libs/Kotlin.jar`

Comment: So, this single JAR archive should actually contain all the Kotlin classes which the compiler generates from your source code (including `HelloKt.class`). Normally, in a Gradle build, Kotlin classes of a project are combined into one or several JAR archives -- that's what you get in `build/libs/`.

Comment: Added the link to another Q&A about running the JAR.