# How to compile Kotlin to include jar of Java with command line?

Tags: command-line, compilation, kotlin

I want to include jar of Java to Kotlin. I tried like below, but I had error.

```
javac -encoding utf-8 javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.java
jar cvf javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.jar javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.class

kotlinc kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.kt -cp javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.jar -include-runtime -d kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.jar

java -jar kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.jar
```

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
javasorce/test/JavaTestClass at CallJavaTestClassKt.main(CallJavaTestClass.kt:5)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javasorce.test.JavaTestClass
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
                ... 1 more
```

I am using like below directories:

```
root
|-javasorce
| |-test
|   |-JavaTestClass.java
|-kotlin
  |-CallJavaTestClass.kt
```

Please tell me if there is solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to compiling the source code with the Java library on the classpath, you need to run the program with the same library on the classpath: if a class is there at compile time, you need it on the classpath at run time as well to be able to use it.

The correct way of running an application which has its classes scattered across several JARs is to pass those JARs as the classpath to `java` and to additionally specify the class that has the `main` function:

```
java CallJavaTestClassKt -cp kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.jar:javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.jar
```

<sup>The command above assumes that you placed the `main` function on top level of `CallJavaTestClass.kt` (in this case, the class name is formed by the file name with `.kt` replaced by `Kt`), and it has no `package ...` declaration. If you have a package, prepend it to the class name as `com.example.FileNameKt`. If you declare `main` in an object or a companion object, use the class name or the object name (without `Kt`) instead of `CallJavaTestClassKt`.</sup>

See also: [**How to run Kotlin class from the command line?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513057/2196460)

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved! Your answer is very very easy to understand!
Most of your answer was correct, but there is a one mistake. The correct way of running an application is not `java CallJavaTestClassKt -cp kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.jar:javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.jar` but `java -cp kotlin/CallJavaTestClass.jar:javasorce/test/JavaTestClass.jar CallJavaTestClassKt`. In your suggestion, `java` could not found CallJavaTestClassKt.