# Steps for using a .jar java library in a Kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to use an external .jar java library in my Kotlin project but I can't find steps on how to do it.  I currently just have the Kotlin command line tool and I haven't started using a build tool (and don't want to for this project so that I can understand exactly what steps a build tool replaces).

The specific library I want to use is [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/download).

Could someone please list the steps involved or direct me to a tutorial on how to do it?

Comment: Does [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856709/how-to-compile-kotlin-to-include-jar-of-java-with-command-line) help you out?

Comment: The easy answer is just use a build tool. Learning about Gradle will take much less time in the end.