# public static void main in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

In `Java`, especially in `Android studio`, every time that I want to run or test some `Java` source code quickly, I will create `public static void main` (shortkey: *`psvm + tab`*) and the IDE will show "Play" button to run it immediately.

[image]

Do we have some kind of `psvm` in `Kotlin` - an entry point or something in order to run or test anything that quickly? Did try with this function but it wasn't working. (Even try with `@JvmStatic`). Can we config somewhere in `Android studio`?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

Comment: I think you need to put it inside a companion object with the @JvmStatic annotation.

Comment: It works. Thank you @TheWanderer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can just put the main function outside of any class.

In anyFile.kt do:

```
package foo

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

[image]

Either `main + tab` or `psvm + tab` work if you have your cursor outside of a class.

Comment: Is there a way use it as the main class for the case of running the app as a jar from command line? I only managed to set it up using the companion object + JvmStatic way.

Comment: I have not done Kotlin development in a while and I cant answer your question off the top of my head, but maybe you find your answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44290802/4265739

Answer (score 32):

Put it inside a companion object with the `@JvmStatic` annotation:

```
class Test {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: or even simple  `object Test {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {}
    }`

Answer (score -3):

Yes, shortkey: *main + <kbd>tab</kbd>* in any *kotlin* file

It will generate

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

}
```

Comment: This does not work inside of a class. (And that was the confusion)

Comment: @leonardkraemer, The question was about how to generate `main` function quickly

Comment: Thanks @OmarMainegra, main + tab works, so does psvm + tab (outside the class). But @ leonardkraemer's answer looks good to me.