# Kotlin:no main manifest attribute, in sample.jar

Tags: java, kotlin

I am just started to learn kotlin from the official doc

1.created a file named sample.kt with the following

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){  
    println("test")
}
```

2. In order to execute

   kotlinc sample.kt -include-runtime -d sample.jar && java -jar sample.jar

But I am getting an error like this

> no main manifest attribute, in sample.jar

I found similar issues related to this but I can't find anything related to kotlin all of them related to java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733566/how-to-run-kotlin-class-from-the-command-line

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733566/how-to-run-kotlin-class-from-the-command-line

Comment: Example `build.gradle.kts` to build your `.jar` with gradle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61373175/7747942