# How to pass compiler arguments to Kotlin Compiler with Gradle

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm compiling a Kotlin library jar with Gradle using the Kotlin gradle plugin:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin'`

I'm trying to find a way to pass a simple `-include-runtime` compiler arguments to the kotlin compiler. I can't seem to find any documentation on this at all. I tried mimicking the java plugin, but that didn't seem to work. [Here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) is some documentation about working with the command line compiler, but the gradle documentation doesn't mention anything about passing compiler arguments.

Comment: Hi! How did you end up solving this problem? :D

Comment: I asked this a few years ago. My need to get this working went away. Looking at the gradle plugin documentation http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html I see that there is a new `freeCompilerArgs` that I might use to pass the necessary arguments. If I couldn't get that working I'd look into building a fat jar or something similar.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can specify compiler args inside `kotlinOptions` closure on tasks of `KotlinCompile` type. For all of them, for instance:

```
allprojects {
    ...

    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '1.6'
            freeCompilerArgs += '-include-runtime'
        }
    }
}
```

[Kotlin docs: using Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html)

Comment: Hi, is this added to the project level gradle file or the module level gradle file?

Comment: It would be for the module that you are applying the kotlin plugin too.

Comment: @deviant, you're right, API is changed. Now `kotlinOptions` are available on `KotlinCompile` tasks, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.includeRuntime = true
}
```

**UPD** btw this exact option `includeRuntime` couldn't work because it is not Gradle way. There are many options to build jar with dependencies in Gradle: [Gradle – Create a Jar file with dependencies](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/), [Gradle Shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)

Comment: You can see it in kotlin's plugin tests for example: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/search?l=gradle&q=compileKotlin&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: @SergeyMashkov This appears not to work for the command `./gradlew clean assemble`. Is there a command that it does work for? On the above comment you left a link to show examples of this being used. I've gone through all the links, and there are no examples of anyone using the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using the kotlin DSL you can try this too:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions.includeRuntime = true
```