# @JvmDefault and how add compiler option

Tags: kotlin, compiler-flags, kotlinc, jvm-default

I need to make a `default void` method in a Kotlin interface. I ran into a problem and a hint said *Usage of `@JvmDefault` is only allowed with `-Xjvm-default` option*.

Where do I need to write this `Xjvm-default`?

Comment: Question is unclear. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 52):

> `@Target([AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY])`
>   annotation class `JvmDefault`
>
> Specifies that a JVM default method should be generated for
>   non-abstract Kotlin interface member.
>
> Usages of this annotation require an explicit compilation argument to
>   be specified: either `-Xjvm-default=enable` or
>   `-Xjvm-default=compatibility`.
>
> with `-Xjvm-default=enable`, only default method in interface is generated for each `@JvmDefault` method. In this mode, annotating an
>   existing method with `@JvmDefault` can break binary compatibility,
>   because it will effectively remove the method from the `DefaultImpls`
>   class.
>
> with `-Xjvm-default=compatibility`, in addition to the default interface
>   method, a compatibility accessor is generated in the 
>   `DefaultImpls` class, that calls the default interface method via a
>   synthetic accessor. In this mode, annotating an existing method with
>   `@JvmDefault` is binary compatible, but results in more methods in
>   bytecode.
>
> Removing this annotation from an interface member is a binary
>   incompatible change in both modes.
>
> Generation of default methods is only possible with JVM target
>   bytecode version 1.8 (`-jvm-target 1.8`) or higher.
>
> `@JvmDefault` methods are excluded from interface delegation.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/index.html

if you use gradle then add this parameter to gradle script

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

for example add this to gradle:

```
kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=compatibility']
}
```

otherwise if you use Kotlinc command line compiler add `-Xjvm-default=compatibility` after your command in command line

Comment: Copying the documentation text without additional information is most probably not very helpful on how to pass flags to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you, but I never received an answer ... How to add to the arguments?

Comment: @Evgesha if you use gradle build system add it to gradle build script https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html

Comment: @Evgesha i added answer to your question in my answer

Comment: I'm trying to apply this answer, but I'm not sure where to put it in my `build.gradle.kts` file. If I put it directly in `tasks`, `kotlinOptions` isn't recognized. If I put it in `tasks` > `compileKotlin`, I get "Unsupported [Collection literals outside of annotation]" as an error on `["-Xjvm-default=compatibility"]`.

Comment: @kshetline if you open  `build.gradle` inside `app` folder there is a `android {  }` put it between `{` and `}` of  `android`

Comment: @Bahman, I'm not doing Android development here, but I did eventually put `kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=enable")` inside both `compileKotlin{ }` and `compileTestKotlin{ }`, and that did the trick. Turns out that `listOf()` syntax was necessary to make Kotlin happy inside a `build.gradle.kts` file.

Comment: Perfect answer. @Evgesha this should be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 27):

The *new* answer since Kotlin 1.4 would be:

```
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile::class).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"

        // For creation of default methods in interfaces
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjvm-default=all")
    }
}
```

You can then even leave off the `@JvmDefault` completely!

Cf. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#default-methods-in-interfaces.

Answer (score 14):

In root `build.gradle` add below code

```
allprojects {
    //Support @JvmDefault
    tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=enable'] //enable or compatibility
            jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This question regarding [`@JvmDefault`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/index.html) seems rather similar [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179996/using-default-function-implementation-of-interface-in-kotlin).

The `-Xjvm-default=enable` flag has to be **passed to the compiler**. Since I assume that you do not work with [`kotlinc`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) (the Kotlin compiler) directly on the command-line: [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31847292/4465208) contains information on how to pass flags to the Kotlin compiler when using Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Additional relevant failure output can be: `is not abstract and does not override abstract method`.

About passing the `-Xjvm-default` flag:

**maven**

in the plugin `configuration` node for [kotlin-maven-plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#specifying-compiler-options) add

```
<args>
  <arg>-Xjvm-default=all</arg>
</args>
```

**IDEA**

in Preferences (via [dev.to](https://dev.to/tommykw/learning-xjvm-default-all-and-xjvm-default-all-compatibility-in-kotlin-2e3m)): Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler -> *Additional command line parameters* add `-Xjvm-default=all`

in Project Structure: Modules -> Kotlin -> *Additional command line parameters* add `-Xjvm-default=all`

`@JvmDefault` should not be necessary with kotlin > 1.4 but there may be special constellations in which the [manual](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-default/) should help determine which combination of annotation and flag is required.