# Generating Swagger/OpenAPI views in Micronaut when using Kotlin only

Tags: kotlin, swagger-ui, openapi, micronaut

The official docs at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-openapi/latest/guide/index.html only describe how to add the `-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=...` compiler flag to the JavaCompile Gradle task:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop'
    ...
}
```

This task is not used though in a pure Kotlin project. I already tried `tasks.withType(compileKotlin)` but without success.

Can anybody give me a hint how to pass the compiler flag in `build.gradle` (still Groovy) for a pure Kotlin project?

Comment: please view my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261044/micronaut-openapi-swagger-is-not-generating-views/67290338#67290338

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for (at least for Micronaut JVM args for OpenApi) is something like this:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += '-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop'
    }
}
```

[See the Kotlin Docs on "Using Gradle -> Compiler Options"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options) for more info generally on how to provide options to the Kotlin Compile step (be sure you're looking at the Groovy Gradle version, as you are not using the Kotlin DSL in your Gradle file)

[This SO question seems to be asking a similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847292/how-to-pass-compiler-arguments-to-kotlin-compiler-with-gradle) and may also be useful

I don't *think* the `fork` option is available in `kotlinOptions` (my suspicion is KotlinCompile already runs in a forked process? Not entirely sure there)

Comment: Thanks, "freeCompilerArgs" was the right thing. My "-D" option still does not work as  kotlinc 1.3.61 does not offer a "-D" and "-Xjavac-arguments=" does not work for my example but I ask the Micronaut Devs what exactly they want to archive.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "but I ask the Micronaut Devs what exactly they want to archive."? What is it you'd like to see from the Micronaut team here?

Comment: I asked how to pass a compiler flag to kotlinc so the answer was technically correct. It does not make the software work though :-) More on that at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-openapi/issues/108

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
kapt {
    arguments {
        arg("micronaut.openapi.views.spec", "redoc.enabled=true,rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop")
    }
}
```