# Is possible to compile kotlin code for run without runtime lib? How?

Tags: kotlin

My case is unusual. Is there any chance to compile code without `kotlin-runtime`? Flags `-Xno-param-assertions` and `-Xno-call-assertions` doesn’t help much, I still got:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lkotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics;
   at lt.neworld.yyy.<init>(Unknown Source:2)
   at lt.neworld.yyy.<init>(yyy.kt:13)
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin runtime is required for running, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565407/3834036) - so I see no reason it will not be required for compilation as well. I guess there is no free lunch :-)

You should either:

- Have Kotlin runtime in the classpath.
- Point to the runtime location when running the app, [as described on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356023/3834036)
- Embed the runtime within the .jar file of the app:

`$ kotlinc <class name> -include-runtime -d <jar name>
 $ java -jar <jar name>`

Comment: Actually, I am not using as backend app, and don't have the luxury for additional 1k methods. Still, I love syntax of kotlin and would like to use it anyway.

Comment: @neworld - can you elaborate what is the unique use-case, then?

Comment: @neworld You definitely need at least the [runtime library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-runtime/1.1.3-2), although not necessarily the [standard library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.1.3-2). There's no way around AFAIK. Perhaps [ProGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) can help reducing the method count after integrating the runtime.

Comment: I want to write a very small library (max 30 methods), fully tested and with my beloved language. +1000 methods are a huge overhead for not-kotlin projects.