# proper way to run kotlin application from gradle task

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I've got simple script

```
package com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

And here is `gradle` task

```
task runExample(type: JavaExec) {
    main ='com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example.Example'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

But when I try to run task `gradle runExample` I get error

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example.Example`

What is the proper way to run application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run compiled class file in Kotlin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355690/how-to-run-compiled-class-file-in-kotlin)

Comment: There is a section on using Gradle application plugin to run a Kotlin app: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26402542/3679676 ... or did you need it to run as-if it is a task in some other way?  But that answer could also give you the clues you need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Thanks to the link [how to run compiled class file in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355690/how-to-run-compiled-class-file-in-kotlin/26402542#26402542) provided by @JaysonMinard
that `main`

```
@file:JvmName("Example")

package com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("executable!")
}
```

and that `task`

```
task runExample(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example.Example'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

did the trick

Comment: Is there a way to get runtimeClasspath for apps with android application plugin?

Comment: how to pass arguments to the main function?

Answer (score 15):

In case you're using a Kotlin buildfile `build.gradle.kts` you would need to do

```
apply {
    plugin("kotlin")
    plugin("application")
}    

configure<ApplicationPluginConvention> {
    mainClassName = "my.cool.App"
}
```

If you apply the `application` plugin using the `plugins {}` block instead you could make it simpler:

```
plugins {
    application
}

application {
    mainClassName = "my.cool.App"
}
```

For details see https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/blob/master/doc/getting-started/Configuring-Plugins.md

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `gradle` application plugin for this.

```
// example.kt
package com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print("executable!")
}
```

add this to your `build.gradle`

```
// build.gradle
apply plugin: "application"
mainClassName = 'com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example.ExampleKt'
```

Then run your application as follows.

```
./gradlew run
```

Comment: For someone having the same stupid problem as me: it should be `apply plugin: "application"` (note the `:` here!)

Comment: it appears the colon is not in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For `build.gradle.kts` users

main file:

```
package com.foo.game.journey.ims.example


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72" // <-- your kotlin version here
}

application {
    mainClassName = "com.lapots.game.journey.ims.example.ExampleKt"
}

...
```

And run with the following command:

```
./gradlew run
```

Comment: this, rather than the `apply { _plugin_}`  is what jetbrains is now pushing.

Answer (score 5):

I found another way from the @lapots answer.

In your `example.kt`:

```kotlin
@file:JvmName("Example")

package your.organization.example

fun main(string: Array<String>) {
    println("Yay! I'm running!")
}
```

Then in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.72"
    application
}

application {
    mainClassName = "your.organization.example.Example"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that post, really helpful :) Configuration is nice and clean :)

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to do it without adding package name. Run your app with the green play icon and it should show the main class name at the end of the command it runs.
[image]

inside `build.gradle` add className and application like this

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.5.10'
    id 'application'
}

mainClassName = 'AppKt'
...
```

now you can do `./gradlew run` and to pass arguments also add `--args='foo --bar'`