# Gradle Task for a sample in project with different main classfile (kotlin, kotlin dsl)

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

So my project has a `Main.kt` file in the sources root.
And there is another `Main.kt` file in a samples folder for a Sample:

```
+
|-src
   |- commonMain
          |- kotlin
          |     |- Main.kt
          |- Samples
                |- InputSample
                       |- Main.kt
```

How do I add a gradle task (kotlin dsl or groovy, at least I need the idea) that is called `InputSample` for example und runs the Main.kt from thee `InputSample` folder?

EDIT:

I think its something like this in groovy gradle dsl but I dont know how to convert it:

```
task app2StartScript(type:CreateStartScripts) {
    applicationName = 'app2'
    classpath = jar.outputs.files
    mainClassName = 'com.example.AppMain2'
    outputDir = file('build/bin')
}
```

Comment: Does InputSample Main.kt run a test?  Just because if it is it would be eaier to stick to gradle conventions if it is

Comment: No. its just a demo I want to ship the Sourcecode with. There are several such demos

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proper way to run kotlin application from gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576170/proper-way-to-run-kotlin-application-from-gradle-task)