# How to run a Kotlin script from within a gradle project that already has a main?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have Ktor project that has a main called `Application.kt`.

The layout is like so

```
.
└── com
    └── myProject
        ├── Application.kt
        ├── Testing.kt
        ├── api
        │   ├── Routes.kt
        │   └── routes
        │       ├── NewRoutes.kt
        │       ├── OpenApiRoutes.kt
        │       └── OldRoutes.kt
        ├── data
        │   ├── Mongo.kt
        │   ├── model
        │   │   ├── model1
        │   │   │   ├── Model1.kt
        │   │   └── model2
        │   │       ├── Model2.kt
        │   └── repository
        │       ├── MongoRepository.kt
        │       └── Repository.kt
```

But now I have a script that I would like to run as part of Kubernetes init container, the file looks like this

```
import com.myProject.data.Mongo
import org.bson.BsonDocument
import org.litote.kmongo.formatJson

class Testing {
  suspend fun test() {
      return whatever
  }

  suspend fun test2() {
     return whatever2
  }
}

suspend fun main() {
  val create = Testing()
  create.test()
  create.test2()
}
```

i've tried running `./gradlew testing` which I have defined in my build.gradle like so:

```
task testing( type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.myProject.Testing'
}
```

but to no avail, does anybody have any ideas?

When trying to run using the above gradle command i get the error `Could not find or load main class Testing`

my build.gradle

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestExceptionFormat

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:6.1.0'
    }
}


task testing( type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.myProject.Testing'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}


tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group 'com.myProject'
version '0.0.1'
mainClassName = "io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain"

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
    test.kotlin.srcDirs = test.java.srcDirs = ['test']
    main.resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
    test.resources.srcDirs = ['testresources']
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()    
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }
}
```

Comment: In any case, I don't believe `main()` can be `suspend`. You should maybe remove the modifier and wrap the body into `runBlocking { ... }` to make it "main-compliant"

Comment: Also what's the name of the file you declared this code in? Because the fully qualified class name for the top-level `main` should be the package name + `.` + file name + `Kt` suffix (unless you use `@file:JvmName` to customize the name of the generated class that wraps top-level declarations)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proper way to run kotlin application from gradle task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576170/proper-way-to-run-kotlin-application-from-gradle-task). If not, please post your exact error so we can help you more easily.

Comment: I updated my question with more information such as project structure and my build.gradle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` function is not part of the `Testing` class. So `com.myProject.Testing` is not a valid main class name.

You should either move your `main` method to the `companion object` of the `Testing` class (like a static method of the class), or change the gradle build file to use the generated class name for top-level declarations, which follows the convention:

package_name + `.` + capitalized_file_name + `Kt`

If your file is named `Testing.kt`, and the package of your declarations is `com.myProject`, your fully qualified main class name should be:

`com.myProject.TestingKt` (note the `Kt` at the end)

But I don't see a `package` declaration at the top of `Testing.kt`. Did you just omit it for brevity or did you actually forget it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following format to define a task:

```
task <task-name>(type: JavaExec) {
    main = '[<package>.]<file-class>'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

where `<task-name>` — the name for a Gradle task, `<package>` — package where your script class resides, `<file-class>` — uppercased filename without extension + `Kt` suffix.

For example, if I call a task `runScript` and the script is located in `/src/main/kotlin/script.kt` (top level package) then the task definition will be the following:

```
task runScript(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'ScriptKt'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: That gives me a `Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for task` error when I run that. I've updated my question with project structure and my build.gradle if that helps at all.

Comment: @Strobe_ just move your task definition after the `apply` plugins block.